# My Windows Service setup.exe doesn't work on Windows Server 2016 machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-server, .net-framework-version

i created an Windows Service application on .Net Framework 4.6 and an installation setup of this project. When i compile my project in release mode, it creates setup.exe and my .msi file. Normally, in Windows 10, my setup.exe and windows service works perfectly. But when i try to run the setup.exe in Windows Server 2016, this image is emerging:

[image]

When i click "Accept" button, ofcourse, it cannot download the .net framework 4.7.2 on windows server 2016.

My project doesn't have any dependecies with .net framework 4.7.2 as far as i know. And i have installed first versions of nugets that i used. Can you help me?

Comment: The nuget must be targeting 4.7.2.  You either need to rebuilt the nuget or install 4.7.2

Comment: @jdweng i uninstalled my nugets and deleted the relevant commands in the code. Rebuilt the solution and installation setup, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: The nuget must need 4.7.2. The are a lot of changes between Net 4.6 and Net 4.7.2 that could break code.  I would update your version of Net to 4.7.2.

Comment: @jdweng oh i understand now thank you :) but i cannot update my net version because my windows service setup must run in Windows Vista or Windows Server 2012 as well. And 4.7.2 not supported on these machines https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies . I guess I have to find another way

Comment: You would need to attempt fixes to nuget to get working with older version.  You also may have issues with TLS versions Vista only uses TLS 1.0.  Windows 2012 may have patch for TLS 1.2 installed.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?force_isolation=true#for-net-framework-35---452-and-not-wcf

Comment: @jdweng you are right, thank you for your informations :) First of all, I try to rebuilt my nuget as you said

Comment: @jdweng hello again! I rebuilt the nuget version 4.0.0 then I try to rebuilt my solution and it says this nuget performs on .net framework > 6.1. So i installed 3.0 and 2.5 versions of nuget and everything was fine. But same message on Windows Server still shows up. Finally, I rebuilt the one of the first versions of nuget ( version: 1.2.1), and Windows Server still want me .net framework 4.7.2 :( Maybe it depends on codes that i wrote, but in 4.5 and 4.6 frameworks there is no such error that indicates the code i wrote is up level for this framework

Comment: As I said you  may need to rewrite some of the nuget code to work on Net 4.6.  There are new encryption modes in later versions of Net that may not work in Net 4.6.  You now have to sharpen your pencil and actual make changes in the code to work with older version of Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fix the problem! Setup Project prerequisites was the problem. In my prerequisites
net framework 4.7.2 version is selected and somehow i couldn't see this! All my solution work perfectly when I changed target .net framework in there.

For more information:
https://www.gonnalearn.com/target-version-net-framework-launch-condition-version/

The last thing "Check the prerequisites" in this website was my solution :)